# Can't make chained Promises work in sequential order (one after another) when each chain reads from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am trying to apply chained Promises to perform a series of Mongoose reads and deletes.

I need the Promise within .next() to start strictly after the previous Promise fully completes execution.

However, the following code does not work as expected:

```
getRidOfOlderShoutsPromise = () => {
     readShoutsPromise('BEFORE')
    .then(() => {
         deleteOlderShoutsPromise();
    })
    .then(() => {
         readShoutsPromise('AFTER')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
}

deleteOlderShoutsPromise = () => {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("in deleteOlderShouts");
        let d = new Date();
        let TwoMinuteAgo = d - 1000 * 90 ;
        All_Shouts.deleteMany({ dateTime: {$lt: TwoMinuteAgo}}, function(err) {
            if (err) reject();
            console.log("DELETED OLDs at "+d);
            resolve();        
        });
    });
}

readShoutsPromise = (tex) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("in readShoutsPromise -"+tex);
        All_Shouts
        .find({})
        .sort([['dateTime', 'ascending']])
        .exec(function (err, data){
            if (err) reject();
            let d = new Date();
            console.log("shouts "+tex+" delete PROMISE = "+data.length +"; date ="+d);
            resolve(data);
        });    
    });
}
```

It prints the following ( 'DELETED OLDs at ...' is printed After 'in readShoutsPromise -AFTER' in console:

```
in readShoutsPromise -BEFORE
shouts BEFORE delete PROMISE = 18; date =Tue Jun 19 2018 21:13:31 GMT+0500
in deleteOlderShouts
in readShoutsPromise -AFTER
DELETED OLDs at Tue Jun 19 2018 21:13:31 GMT+0500
shouts AFTER delete PROMISE = 14; date =Tue Jun 19 2018 21:13:31 GMT+0500
```

or

```
in readShoutsPromise -BEFORE
shouts BEFORE delete PROMISE = 18; date =Tue Jun 19 2018 21:13:31 GMT+0500
in deleteOlderShouts
in readShoutsPromise -AFTER
shouts AFTER delete PROMISE = 14; date =Tue Jun 19 2018 21:13:31 GMT+0500
DELETED OLDs at Tue Jun 19 2018 21:13:31 GMT+0500
```

This is not what is expected.

What should do to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution ( found solution not on this website, but in articles/tutorials referred below ).

All I had to do is to add 'return' before function calls which define my Promises. [This tutorial](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b) states that 'return' is important to achieve this and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/quick-code/javascript-promises-in-twenty-minutes-3aac5b65b887) gives few examples of this being applied.

```
getRidOfOlderShoutsPromise = () => {
    return readShoutsPromise('BEFORE')
    .then(() => {
        return deleteOlderShoutsPromise();
    })
    .then(() => {
        return readShoutsPromise('AFTER')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
}
```

After adding 'return's it consistently prints the following as expected:

```
in readShoutsPromise -BEFORE
shouts BEFORE delete PROMISE = 18 date =Tue Jun 19 2018 22:04:42 GMT+0500
in deleteOlderShouts
DELETED OLDs at Tue Jun 19 2018 22:04:42 GMT+0500
in readShoutsPromise -AFTER
shouts AFTER delete PROMISE = 9 date =Tue Jun 19 2018 22:04:42 GMT+0500
```

And (note for complete beginners) - resolve(); or reject(); should be within ,function(err) {} or  .exec(function (err, data){} parts of your promises.